Copy on CIFS folder create 0 byte file
i'm trying to mount a CIFS folder on my Ubuntu 22.04 - 6.5.0-28-generic machine.
The folder is on our company Windows Domain Controller, is mounted on several other Windows VMs and is working flawlessly.
However, when this folder is mounted on my PC (or other pc with ubuntu, same version and kernel) i can no longer copy a file: the target file remain at 0 byte.
The folder is mounted with a fstab line that is like:
//dc.domain.lan/serverfile /home/user/SERVER/ cifs credentials=/home/user/credfile.txt,users,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noexec 0 0

very strangely, if the copy is done from terminal with cp it is successful. i have tried using different file managers (nautilus and dolphin) but the result is the same
Searching on google i found that was possibly a kernel issue so i tried to boot with an older version, and with 6.5.0-26-generic I'm able to copy files.
I didn't find anyone else with the same problem, so I have no idea what else to do, tail -f on /var/log/kern.log and /var/log/dmesg shows nothing useful and I wouldn't know what other logs to check.
Please, instead of downvoting the question, in case there is something wrong, write a comment and I will be sure to update the question with anything else you think is necessary

Turns out it was a kernel problem, waiting for a new release and upgrading solved the problem.
The kernel with the patch is 6.5.0-35-generic.
Sometime all you can do is wait.
